# How JPA knows the foreign key field from a mappedBy attribute?

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, openjpa

In this example [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492874/ORM/databases/Naive-MappedBy-attribute-OneToMany)

I understand what the `mappedBy` attribute is doing. It is telling JPA that the foreign key exists in Users table. But the foreign key in db is a field, but here they are designating a whole object

> BillingInfo

as foreign key. How does JPA know which field inside BillingInfo object serves as foreign key?

Comment: Post the example here.

Answer (score 0):

`mappedBy = "billingInfo"` doesn't say where the foreign key is. It's telling Hibernate that the annotated field (`user`) constitutes the inverse side of a bidirectional association, and that the owning side of this association is the field `User.billingInfo`.

Hibernate thus looks how the `User.billingInfo` is mapped to know how this bidirectional association must be mapped.
In this case, the only annotation on `User.billingInfo` is `@OneToOne`. Since that doesn't say how the association is mapped, the defaults specified in the JPS specification will apply, and, IIRC, a join column named `"billingInfo_id"` will be used.

Comment: Thanks. But the explanation is a bit too text book for me. Is it possible to state it using simpler language?i really don't get this:  "constitutes the inverse side of a bidirectional association, and that the owning side of this association is the field User.billingInfo"